# Completely uninstalling Windows 8.1 + Prepare automatic recovery

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, grub

My computer earlier was on a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. But then I uninstalled Windows 8.1 to replace it with some other Linux OS.

I don't know whether what I did was proper uninstalling as I just formatted the Windows containing partition of my hard drive.

After uninstalling , the next time grub loaded , it was showing Windows 8.1 in its options . Also the `sudo update-grub` echoes that it has detected windows. What's the problem?

Also in that partition I tried to install Kali but using boot settings in ubuntu. When I selected it to boot with USB containing Kali , it didn't boot with kali and on the next restart it has starting booting with OS Boot manager (for windows).
It shows `Preparing automatic recovery ..` screen and then goes onto the `diagnosing your PC` screen. Then it shows `Repairing disk errors. This might take over an hour to complete.` and finally gives a screen like this:

[image: 1]

**Note** : Just that the D:/ in the image is replaced by an X:/ in my case

Comment: X:\ indicates a WinRE environment.  Are you sure its X:\?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't X:/ . it was just \\: the X was being shown in the command prompt

Comment: Can you provide us the exact message?  The details matter.  In any event your Windows installation is corrupt to the point it can't even repair itself which is an indicating is beyond repair.

Comment: Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC   LogFile:`\\\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddisk\Volume4\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt`